# Symfony i18n fromat_number_choice doesn't work as it should

Tags: internationalization, symfony-1.4

I have the following code with uses `format_number_choice` in Symfony 1.4:

```
<?php echo format_number_choice(
        '[0]You do not have any remaining invites.|[1]You have one invite.|(1,+Inf]You have %1% invites.', array('%1%' => $users->getInvitatii()), $users->getInvitatii(), 'nrchoice') ?>
```

The translation string looks like this:

```
<trans-unit id="2" approved="yes">
        <source>[0]You do not have any remaining invites.|[1]You have one invite.|(1,+Inf]You have %1% invites.</source>
        <target state="translated">[0]Nu mai aveți nicio invitație|[1]Mai aveți o invitație|{n: n % 100 < 20} Mai aveți %1% invitații.|{n: n % 100 > 20} Mai aveți %1% de invitații.</target>
</trans-unit>
```

In Romanian, there are 2 types of plurals: `number%100 < 20` and `number%100 >= 20`. The only problem is that my string isn't translated and I guess there is an error in my syntax, but I can't figure out where is the problem. I found this syntax in the Symfony 1.4 Documentation.

Comment: Do you get an error? Have you tried to write the source in english with the 2 plurals instead of keeping the default choice?

Comment: Well, this is an interesting fact: it works perfectly if I use that syntax directly in the format_number_choice. It just doesn't want to work with the translated string.

Comment: @Daniel Try to encode ">" as "&gt;" and "<" as "&lt;" because those are invalid in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try that:

The php code :

```
<?php echo format_number_choice(
  '[0]You do not have any remaining invites.|[1]You have one invite|{n: n % 100 < 20} You have %1% invites.|{n: n % 100 > 20} You have %1% invites.', 
  array('%1%' => $users->getInvitatii()), $users->getInvitatii(), 'nrchoice')
?>
```

Inside your translation file:

```
<trans-unit id="2" approved="yes">
  <source>[0]You do not have any remaining invites.|[1]You have one invite|{n: n % 100 < 20} You have %1% invites.|{n: n % 100 > 20} You have %1% invites.</source>
  <target state="translated">[0]Nu mai aveți nicio invitație|[1]Mai aveți o invitație|{n: n % 100 < 20} Mai aveți %1% invitații.|{n: n % 100 > 20} Mai aveți %1% de invitații.</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Comment: What's inside your node `file` form your xliff file?